# Spring Boot / Angular index.html

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I have my login page as the index.html inside of my spring boot application. How would I route my Angular application to point to that. I have sup[lied the code I have thus far. Any input or comments would be greatly appreciated. This is the Error that i receive. Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/

login.component.html

```
<div>
  <button (click)="getLoginPage()" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</div>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {LoginService} from "../../service/login.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginPage = '';

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLoginPage();
  }

  public getLoginPage(): void {
    this.loginService.getLoginPage().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.loginPage = response;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  private apiServerUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getLoginPage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>( this.apiServerUrl);
  }
}
```

enviroment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080'
};
```

CorsFilter

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
            "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
    corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  public getLoginPage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>( this.apiServerUrl, {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        }),
       'responseType': 'text'
       });
  }
```

Comment: This resolved the Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/ error however it is now giving me a 404 error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that http://localhost:8080/ returns something?

Comment: I added the corsfilter that I created... perhaps this might be causing issues. not certain why localhost:8080 wont return anything and getting a 404

Comment: Try to remove the corsfilter and show the result.
Or just create a different post that's more specific in this new issue